# What causes System.loadLibrary() to fail on linux (RPi)?

Tags: java, linux

I am using a library that calls `System.loadLibrary()` in Java to load up some native code that is compiled as a C shared-library with a `.so` extension. Nothing major there, I have done it before and works (on Android and Mac OS X).

The problem I am having is that the java application fails to load the .so file when running on the Raspberry Pi (Raspbian Distrobution).

Why is this, what causes it to fail and how do I fix.

For clarity:

- I am aware that I need to load the binary for the correct architecture. For the Raspberry Pi I am using the binary for `linux-arm`
- I have also set up the correct path so it should be found. I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `java.library.path` with no success

Update 1:

As pcarter has suggested, I have tried using `-verbose:jni`. There doesn't appear to be any errors but please see this output:

```
    [Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Object.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Object.hashCode]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Object.wait]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Object.notify]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Object.notifyAll]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Object.clone]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.System.nanoTime]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.System.arraycopy]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Thread.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.start0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.stop0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.isAlive]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.suspend0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.resume0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.setPriority0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.yield]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.sleep]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.currentThread]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.countStackFrames]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.interrupt0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.isInterrupted]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.holdsLock]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.getThreads]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.dumpThreads]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Thread.setNativeName]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.security.AccessController.getStackAccessControlContext ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.security.AccessController.getInheritedAccessControlContext ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Class.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getName0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getSuperclass]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getInterfaces0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getClassLoader0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.isInterface]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getSigners]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.setSigners]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.isArray]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.isPrimitive]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getComponentType]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getModifiers]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getProtectionDomain0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getDeclaredClasses0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getGenericSignature0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getRawAnnotations]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getConstantPool]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.desiredAssertionStatus0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getEnclosingMethod0]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Class.getRawTypeAnnotations]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.ClassLoader.retrieveDirectives]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Float.floatToRawIntBits ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Double.doubleToRawLongBits ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.initProperties ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.misc.VM.initialize ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.misc.Unsafe.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getObjectVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putObjectVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getBoolean]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putBoolean]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getBooleanVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putBooleanVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByteVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByteVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getShortVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putShortVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getCharVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putCharVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getIntVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putIntVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLongVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putLongVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getFloatVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putFloatVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getDoubleVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putDoubleVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getAddress]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putAddress]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.reallocateMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.freeMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.objectFieldOffset]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldOffset]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldBase]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.addressSize]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.pageSize]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getObjectVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putObjectVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getBoolean]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putBoolean]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getBooleanVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putBooleanVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByteVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByteVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getShortVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putShortVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getCharVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putCharVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getIntVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putIntVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLongVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putLongVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getFloatVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putFloatVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getDoubleVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putDoubleVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putByte]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putShort]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putChar]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putFloat]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putDouble]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getAddress]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putAddress]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.reallocateMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.freeMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.objectFieldOffset]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldOffset]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.staticFieldBase]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.ensureClassInitialized]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayBaseOffset]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.arrayIndexScale]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.addressSize]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.pageSize]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.monitorEnter]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.monitorExit]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.tryMonitorEnter]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.throwException]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putOrderedObject]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putOrderedInt]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.putOrderedLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.park]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.unpark]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.getLoadAverage]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.setMemory]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.shouldBeInitialized]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.loadFence]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Unsafe.fullFence]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.String.intern ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Object.getClass ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Class.forName0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.reflect.Reflection.getClassAccessFlags ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Runtime.maxMemory ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileInputStream.initIDs ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileDescriptor.initIDs ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileOutputStream.initIDs ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.setIn0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.setOut0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.setErr0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.UnixFileSystem.initIDs ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.mapLibraryName ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.findBuiltinLib ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.misc.Signal.findSignal ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.misc.Signal.handle0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Compiler.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Compiler.compileClass]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Compiler.compileClasses]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Compiler.command]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Compiler.enable]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.Compiler.disable]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileInputStream.open ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileInputStream.available ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.reflect.Array.newArray ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileInputStream.close0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.UnixFileSystem.list ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Runtime.availableProcessors ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.init]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.expand]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.resolve]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.getConstant]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.getNamedCon]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.getMembers]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.objectFieldOffset]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.setCallSiteTargetNormal]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.setCallSiteTargetVolatile]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.staticFieldOffset]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.staticFieldBase]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.getMemberVMInfo]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invoke]
[Registering JNI native method java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeExact]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.find ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.initIDs ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.UnixFileSystem.getLastModifiedTime ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.open ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.misc.Perf.registerNatives ... JNI]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Perf.attach]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Perf.detach]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Perf.createLong]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Perf.createByteArray]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Perf.highResCounter]
[Registering JNI native method sun.misc.Perf.highResFrequency]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getTotal ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.startsWithLOC ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryFlag ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryTime ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.TimeZone.getSystemTimeZoneID ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryCrc ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntrySize ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryCSize ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryMethod ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryBytes ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.freeEntry ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.Inflater.initIDs ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.Inflater.init ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.read ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.Inflater.reset ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.Inflater.end ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.zip.ZipFile.close ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.jar.JarFile.getMetaInfEntryNames ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Package.getSystemPackage0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes ... JNI]
*** Loading hardcoded library
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.System.identityHashCode ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceDepth ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Throwable.getStackTraceElement ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.Class.isInstance ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong.VMSupportsCS8 ... JNI]
[Dynamic-linking native method java.lang.reflect.Proxy.defineClass0 ... JNI]
Working Directory = /home/pi/conor/JavaGo
```

And with regards to the exact error, please see the following:

Message body full, please see [this paste](http://pastebin.com/60VC5mbG) for stacktrace but the main error in the stacktrace is as follows:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jffi-1.2 in java.library.path
```

I would like to reiterate that I have set the path accordingly using, `-Djava.library.path` and also `-DLD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: in a past project, I was having similar difficulties and it turned out that even though I *thought* I had set the library path correctly, it was not being set. 

Are you 100%, absolutely sure it is indeed being set correctly?

Comment: Unfortunately I a sure it is correct :(

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? Have you tried adding the  `-verbose:jni` option to the `java` program launcher to debug?

Comment: I have updated my question with the requested info. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (1) Dumpling java.library.path. (2) A small C program to check whether the .so works on Raspberry Pi?

Comment: JFFI is the Java Foreign Function Interface. If it is needed (version 1.2) and can not be accessed (not in path) maybe this causes the error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262167/java-lang-runtimeexception-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-could-not-locate-stu

Comment: @ralfhtp Interesting.. You can see my comment on the answer. Can you understand what the user did?

Answer (score 0):

i make an answer because of the code. You can use this to see your *java.library.path*

```
public class JavaLibPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String libPathProperty = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        System.out.println(libPathProperty);
    }
}
```

Then check if jffi-1.2 can be found in this path or if it is on your computer anyway

https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-library-path-what-is-it-and-how-to-use/ says:

*When a Java application loads a native library using the* `System.loadLibrary()` *method, the java.library.path is scanned for the specified library. If the JVM is not able to detect the requested library, it throws an* `UnsatisfiedLinkError` *. Finally, the usage of native libraries makes a Java program more platform dependent, as it requires the existence of specific native libraries.*

UPDATE: It seems that *jffi  is not installed by default on RPi*, see this link http://peterwawood.blogspot.de/2014/07/compling-jffi-on-raspberry-pi.html and this [How to build JRuby 1.7.13 on Raspberry Pi with rbenv/ruby-build?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24718972/how-to-build-jruby-1-7-13-on-raspberry-pi-with-rbenv-ruby-build)